# Using JavaScript es6 Array.find() with an array of ID's

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
const promotions = [{ Id: 14 }, { Id: 255 }, { Id: 23 }, { Id: 56 }]; 
const timePromotionIds = [255,56];

const promos = promotions.find(promotion => {
      return promotion.Id === timePromotionIds.map(timePromotionId => {
        return timePromotionId;
      });
    });
```

I want to return the objects in promotions that match the ID's in the timePromotionIds array.

I've also tried:

```
const promos = promotions.find(promotion => {
      return timePromotionIds.map(timePromotionId => {
        return promotion.Id === timePromotionId;
      });
    });
```

Which is getting me the first object, but not any others. Bit better but not quite there.

Is this possible? I'm clearly doing something wrong!

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Use filter. [`const promos = promotions.filter(o => timePromotionIds.includes(o.Id));`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1e65gkrc/) If `includes` is not supported, use `indexOf`.

Comment: `Array#map` returns another array.. Not element...

Comment: @Tushar, that should be the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar but now it's returning an empty array. Any ideas? I need to have an array of these objects that matched returned.

Comment: @Tushar - You are totally correct. This works. What threw me off was because I was getting an array of strings and not numbers. i.e. ["255","56"]. Using map on this array and parsing as numbers now works with your method. Please submit an answer below and I'll mark you as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out the objects which [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the id from the `timePromotionIds` array.

```
const promotions = [{ Id: 14 }, { Id: 255 }, { Id: 23 }, { Id: 56 }]; 
const timePromotionIds = [255,56];

const promos = promotions.filter((promo) => {  
  return timePromotionIds.includes(promo.Id); 
});

console.log(promos);
```

Result:

```
[Object { Id=255}, Object { Id=56}]
```

Please note because `filter` returns the filtered element you have to return the elements after you call the `contains` method.

Comment: What does your last paragraph mean?